# mid interval percentile with data.table organized by multiple colums

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data set for which I want to calculate mid interval percentiles (I got the basic code from jlhoward). Now I am attempting to add a condition for groups using (by). Although it works with a single condition, it does not work when I add two conditions. 
The problem appears to be with the **by**

```
rm(list=ls())
library(data.table)
ID<-c(43574,43574,43574,43835,43835,43902,43902,44053,44053,44331,44331,44424,44424,44534,44534,44575,47161,47177,47177,47178,47178,47179,47179,47186,47186,47222,47222,47237,47237,47239,47239,47244,47244,47292,47292,47293,47293,47296,47296,47299,45519,45519,45768,45768,45912,46381,47291,47855,47927,47970,47970,48357,48357,500325,500345,500377,500419,500516,500516,500661,500789,501799,32474,34358,34358,34439,34798,36521,36521,36730,36730,37651,40621,41502,43544,45297,46929)
TOPIC<-c("M","M","R","M","R","R","M","R","M","M","R","M","R","M","R","M","M","M","R","R","M","M","R","M","R","M","R","R","M","M","R","M","R","R","M","M","R","M","R","R","R","M","R","M","R","R","R","M","R","R","M","M","R","R","R","R","R","R","M","R","R","R","R","M","R","R","M","M","R","M","R","R","R","R","R","R","R")
SCORE<-c(189,189,185,184,176,153,172,195,192,198,198,173,166,198,188,198,218,203,213,217,217,227,213,220,210,218,210,204,206,221,209,242,224,209,209,213,216,233,214,217,229,226,196,200,214,226,224,222,226,221,217,214,214,224,219,220,214,222,226,225,243,214,182,162,158,226,170,218,208,191,197,216,220,216,220,206,226)
GROUP<-c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12)
CalculatedPtile<-c(0.44,0.44,0.50,0.28,0.36,0.07,0.06,0.79,0.61,0.83,0.93,0.17,0.21,0.83,0.64,0.83,0.50,0.04,0.50,0.83,0.38,0.79,0.50,0.63,0.33,0.50,0.33,0.04,0.13,0.71,0.17,0.96,0.96,0.17,0.21,0.29,0.71,0.88,0.63,0.83,0.91,0.83,0.03,0.08,0.19,0.81,0.63,0.58,0.81,0.47,0.42,0.25,0.19,0.63,0.34,0.41,0.19,0.53,0.83,0.72,0.97,0.19,0.14,0.13,0.05,0.91,0.38,0.88,0.41,0.63,0.23,0.55,0.73,0.55,0.73,0.32,0.91)
DT <- data.table(ID,TOPIC,SCORE,GROUP,CalculatedPtile)
#
#insert Splitting variable here and it works
#
ptile.dt <- DT[,sapply(SCORE,function(x)  (sum(SCORE==x)/2+sum(SCORE<x))/.N),by=list(GROUP,TOPIC)]$V1
DT$ptile<- round(ptile.dt,2)
View(DT)
```

*splitting variable*

#DT<-DT[TOPIC=="M"]

If I insert and uncomment the above (splitting variable), 
it works fine for when TOPIC is equal to "M", but when I comment it out, the ptile.dt calculations do not appear to be taking into account the TOPIC as expected?

## Why???

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not in front of an R-console right now, but couldn't you use the ```ecdf``` function for this?  Maybe this is a dumb suggestion by wouldn't ```DT[ , ptile := 1-ecdf(SCORE)(SCORE), by=list(GROUP,TOPIC)]``` work?  It seems like your approach would be sensitive to ordering.

Comment: For example (This works for this example)     ptile.mt <- MT[,sapply(SCORE,function(x)  (sum(SCORE==x)/2+sum(SCORE<x))/.N),by=list(GROUP,TOPIC)]$V1;    ptile.rt <- RT[,sapply(SCORE,function(x)  (sum(SCORE==x)/2+sum(SCORE<x))/.N),by=list(GROUP,TOPIC)]$V1;    MT$ptile<- round(ptile.mt,2);    RT$ptile<- round(ptile.rt,2);    CT<-rbind(MT,RT)

Comment: Hi Mike, no, unfortunately the ecdf does not work. There are two problems (1. pasting in your code I got an error when I attempted to add back into the data table  Error in Math.data.frame(list(ID = c(43574, ... non-numeric variable in data frame: TOPIC and 2. The data are incorrect (as in the above problem). Can you be more specific about what you meant by "It seems like your approach would be sensitive to ordering."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be a better way to think about this.

```
DT[ , rank := rank(SCORE,ties.method="min"), by=list(GROUP,TOPIC)]
DT[ , ties := .N, by=list(GROUP,TOPIC,SCORE)]
DT[ , total :=.N, by=list(GROUP,TOPIC)]
DT[ , ptile := (ties*0.5+(rank-1))/total]
DT[ , ptile := round(ptile,2)]
```

Comment: Thank you. Your response is very readable, easy to follow and best of all it does exactly what I want!